# Default Binding and Default Schema is coming blank in local db, after running SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to copy database from SQL server 2012 which is hosted on AWS, to my local SQL server 2012 Database, I had tried couple of ways to perform this task, keep on getting similar issue with all of them << Default Binding and Default Schema is coming blank>> in local database after running SSIS Package. not sure why it's not getting copied from source database

FYI...

I had tried same in Local database server, to copy one db to another, still same issue, I am very sure nothing to do with AWS

Import/Export data
Created SSIS Package using 
<< Transfer Database Task>>
<>

Please suggest me how to fix this issue, is this expected behaviour in SSIS..? do we have any work around to fix this problem..?

Source DB Screen

[image]